# Adding a title before several paragraphs of a certain paragraph style

Tags: adobe-indesign, grep

In Indesign, I need to insert a fixed title (something like - "law") before each group of paragraphs of a certain paragraph style, and another title right after it (something like - "interpretation of the law"). How can I do this using GREP? When I tried to search for the paragraph style, what I got (at best) is one paragraph at a time, but I want to insert **before** and **after** a group of such paragraphs, as mentioned. (And in the worst case, I only get half a paragraph, in case there are additional characters throughout the paragraph).

[image: The way I want to insert the headers]

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14093452/grep-only-the-first-match-and-stop and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24014194/how-to-grep-the-last-occurrence-of-a-line-pattern

Comment: @Scott This is completely unrelated to my question, unfortunately. Thanks anyway.

Comment: In my investigating, searching for a paragraph style without anything in the “Find what” field will highlight all consecutive paras in that style. You could then escape out, left arrow, paste your “Law” heading, repeat. Then run through again, but instead of left arrow, right arrow, paste your “After Law” heading, and repeat.